Apache Tika: Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10 in metadata.names()
We are using ApacheTika for content extraction from text/pdf files and getting this error while accessing the metadata.names().
This is not consistently happening but around 2-3% cases where this error occurs.
Code:
public ExtractionResponse getText(InputStream sourceInputStream, int maxExtractedStringLength) {
    tika.setMaxStringLength(maxExtractedStringLength);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    try {
        Reader extractedContentReader = tika.parse(sourceInputStream, metadata);
        ReaderInputStream readerInputStream =ReaderInputStream.builder().setReader(extractedContentReader).get();
        return ExtractionResponse.of(readerInputStream, getMetadatas(metadata), StringUtils.EMPTY);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("Error in file extraction", e);
        throw new ApplicationRuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private String getMetadatas(Metadata metadata) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> metadataMap = Stream.of(metadata.names())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), name -> asList(metadata.getValues(name))));
    return JSONUtil.generateJSON(metadataMap);
}

Exception:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 14 out of bounds for length 14
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.keysToArray(HashMap.java:950)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySet.toArray(HashMap.java:997)
at org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata.names(Metadata.java:156)
at com.myzone.extractors.TikaDocumentHandler.getMetadatas(TikaDocumentHandler.java:81)
at com.myzone.extractors.TikaDocumentHandler.getText(TikaDocumentHandler.java:54)


Are you trying to read the values whilst parsing is still taking place?

@Gagravarr, Trying the read the metadata after the parsing completed and tika returns the reader.

Please tell what tika version you are using and share the PDF.

Using tika-core:2.9.0', this is intermittent and not giving errors when retry the extraction for file so it's really surprising case.

The current version is 2.9.2. Try to create a scenario with specific files so that it always happens after some time.
